# How to load items in a RecyclerView in the same order as the API calls are done?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

**That's my problem**:

I need to display some items in a RecyclerView in the same order they are called from the server to match the given design. However, I think I may probably be missing something very obvious on how Java actually works, because even though my calls are done in order, I've noticed the code placed after them is executed before a result is got from the server and afterwards, when the UI is updated, the order for the items displayed is not the same as originally intended.

That's the piece of code that has been taken away some days of my life now..

```
    getGetMetricRangeAPI("bp_dia");
    getGetMetricRangeAPI("bp_sys");
    getGetMetricRangeAPI("glucose");
    getGetMetricRangeAPI("lung_fev1");
    getGetMetricRangeAPI("vo2");
    getGetMetricRangeAPI("visceral");
    getGetMetricRangeAPI("body_fat");

    mGoalsRecyclerView.setAdapter(mGoalsAdapter);
    GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
    mGoalsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mGoalsRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

    // mGoalsList is returning empty, as it should update *after* the 
    // response from the server, but for some reason, and that's what is 
    // confusing me a lot at the moment, that part of the code is read 
    // before it, so this whole for loop is being ignored at the moment.
    for (GetAdvancedGoal goal : mGoalsList) {

        mGoalsAdapter.addItem(goal);

    }
```

Any help on that is really very much appreciated!! Thanks a lot!!! :)

Ps: I think another title for my question could be: 
**How do I make sure actions happen sequentially in Java?**
As if I could make sure I can populate my adapter **only when** the mGoalsList array is completely filled (or even the hashmap, as per the suggestions), I could then order and display the items according to the desired sequence.

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: this depends on your implementation, but usually, when consuming an API in Android, its result should be returned in a callback (either success or fail), this way you can add the data to your adapter ONLY when the success callback gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple API calling at same time, there must be dependency  between all this. For ordering of list according to api calling, you can use numbering assigned to each api calling and create hashmap of return result with numbers and displaying of list can be done according to numbers. But this is worst idea i think.

For better and pure solution, if a core developer. you must go for RxJava, you must be hearing about this. Here is description link:
[RxJava](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/RxJava/article.html)

In RxJava, you defines dependency between calling of api's, here you can define observer's and observable's. Where Observer's always listen to observable(Sorry find detail description in link), so you must be insure that. 4th api should be call always after 2nd or 3rd one. Go for it, sorry i don't have any code related to that right now. if i will got that will post here.

Comment: Hello @ankit, thanks very much for your reply. Much appreciated! I am actually a JR developer, so haven't got the chance to look into RxJava yet, although having heard of it, but will keep your reply in mind and will look up about it. In the meantime, will try to give a goal to the other hashmap solution, as that may be a bit closer to what I know so far. Thanks again!

Comment: Not at all bro. It's my pleasure to help everyone

Comment: Thanks @ankit! Could I just ask you for a favour, please? If you ever happen to come across a sample of how to solve this problem using RxJava would you mind posting it here? I've got very curious about it and tried to implement it but I think it may be a bit ahead of what I am able to do at the moment, although probably being the most elegant solution. Thanks a lot again and have a lovely day! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
getGetMetricRangeAPI("bp_dia",1);
getGetMetricRangeAPI("bp_sys",2);
getGetMetricRangeAPI("glucose",3);
getGetMetricRangeAPI("lung_fev1",4);
getGetMetricRangeAPI("vo2",5);
getGetMetricRangeAPI("visceral",6);
getGetMetricRangeAPI("body_fat",7);
```

Add an integer to your API call. Save the response in a HashMap and sort it according to this order

Comment: Hi @Ameer, thanks a lot for your reply. I'm trying to implement your answer at the moment. Have updated my question on what I have done so far. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (GetAdvancedGoal goal : mGoalsList) {
    mGoalsAdapter.addItem(goal);
}

//this is missing in your code
mGoalsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: Hi @maddy, thanks very much for your reply. I've added a comment to my question, as the whole for loop is actually not being read at the moment. mGoalsList should update as part of the response from the server, but for some reason this part of the code is read before that, when mGoalsList is still empty.. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

That's the implementation of the hashmap suggestion that solved my problem

Added answer from @Ammer on my fragment

```
getGetMetricRangeAPI("bp_dia",1);
getGetMetricRangeAPI("bp_sys",2);
getGetMetricRangeAPI("glucose",3);
getGetMetricRangeAPI("lung_fev1",4);
getGetMetricRangeAPI("vo2",5);
getGetMetricRangeAPI("visceral",6);
getGetMetricRangeAPI("body_fat",7);
```

And that's my adapter using hashmap instead of arraylist

```
public void addItem(final GetAdvancedGoal item, int position) {

    if (position == 0) {

        mHashMap.put(item, 0);
        mHashMapInvertedKeyValue.put(0, item);

    } else if (position == 1) {

        mHashMap.put(item, 1);
        mHashMapInvertedKeyValue.put(1, item);

    } else if (position == 2) {

        mHashMap.put(item, 2);
        mHashMapInvertedKeyValue.put(2, item);

    } else if (position == 3) {

        mHashMap.put(item, 3);
        mHashMapInvertedKeyValue.put(3, item);

    } else if (position == 4) {

        mHashMap.put(item, 4);
        mHashMapInvertedKeyValue.put(4, item);

    } else if (position == 5) {

        mHashMap.put(item, 5);
        mHashMapInvertedKeyValue.put(5, item);

    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    GetAdvancedGoal getAdvancedGoal = null;


    if (mHashMapInvertedKeyValue.get(position) != null) {

        getAdvancedGoal = mHashMapInvertedKeyValue.get(position);

        // Name
        holder.update_goal_editText.setText(getAdvancedGoal.getValue());


        // Image
        int id = getAdvancedGoal.getImageID();

        switch (id) {
            case R.drawable.blood_pressure:

                SharedPreferences preferences = mActivity.getSharedPreferences("ADVANCED_METRIC_BP_SYS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String valueSys = preferences.getString("bp_sys", "");


                holder.update_goal_editText.setText(getAdvancedGoal.getValue() + "/" + valueSys);
                holder.goal_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.blood_pressure);
                break;

            case R.drawable.glucose_level:
                holder.goal_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.glucose_level);
                break;

            case R.drawable.visceral_fat:
                holder.goal_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.visceral_fat);
                break;

            case R.drawable.lung_function:
                holder.goal_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.lung_function);
                break;


            case R.drawable.v02_max:
                holder.goal_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.v02_max);
                break;

            case R.drawable.body_fat:
                holder.goal_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.body_fat);
                break;

        }

    }


}
```